# Haskell memory management under IOS 5

Tags: ios, haskell, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I want to embed Haskell engine into IOS 5 project as a C library - to run Haskell code inside the IOS app. So I have several questions:

1. Is there any known memory management problem that Haskell reveals under ARC?
2. How could I ensure that Haskell did not interfere with IOS memory management?
3. What may be an effective strategy for dealing with these issues?

Comment: I edited your question to be more specific about the issue you seem to have raised. You should ask your fourth point (unrelated to memory management) in a separate question.

Comment: GHC Cross compiles to ARM now? :O

Comment: ARC and its semantics target Objective-C specifically. It will release and retain for you with a static analysis that only works for Objective-C. This memory management is called reference counting garbage collection, but for some reason Apple refused to call it a garbage collector. So you can see it as manual memory management, except it was added by the compiler. Hence it should not affect a C library AFAIK, as it does not use Objective-C semantics.

Comment: @fisk: Apple most likely don't refer to ARC as garbage collection for two reasons, 1) because the term garbage collection has generally been used to mean the mark and sweep variety used by Java and other modern languages that relies on a runtime thread to clean up memory, which Apple specifically want to make clear is *not* how ARC works, and 2) because Objective C already has a mark and sweep garbage collection system called "Objective-C garbage collection" which is used on Mac OS and predates ARC, so again, calling ARC garbage collection would cause much confusion.

Comment: @NickLockwood What you meant is probably tracing garbage collectors. Mark and sweep is one variant. Replicating and copying collectors are other tracing garbage collectors.

Comment: @fisk Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC is strictly a compile-time code generation process that relates to Objective-C code. ARC basically means "inserting retain, release and autorelease statements into the source* at compilation time so the programmer doesn't have to".

Consequently, ARC won't do anything to non-Objective C code (i.e. regular C libraries) and has no runtime behaviour** that might interfere with the garbage collection behaviour of the Haskell engine.

*That's not actually how ARC works, it generates optimised assembly code, not source code, but as an analogy it's a good description of how it works.

**Strictly speaking, it's not true that ARC has no runtime behaviour, as there is the weak pointer management that happens at runtime, but again that applies only to Objective-C objects and won't do anything to Haskell code.